# Preparing a sequence of functions to be plotted in one plot

Tags: plotting

So, I'm having a bit of an issue with this code that I'm trying to write. I've written (and working) a part that does the quadratic spline from a list of points. In this case I'm trying to show the accuracy of such a spline from uniform points along the `Cos[6*Pi*x]` function by changing the number of sample points.

```
ClearAll[data, a, b, c, d, x, y, S, Sp, eqns]
xdata = Table [i, {i, 0, 1, .20}];
ydata = Table[Cos[6*Pi*i], {i, 0, 1, .20}];
data = Transpose[{xdata, ydata}];

dataplot = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black];

S[i_][x_] = a[i] + b[i]*x + c[i]*x^2;
Do[x[i_] := data[[i, 1]], {i, 1, Length[data]}];
Do[y[i_] := data[[i, 2]], {i, 1, Length[data]}];
eqns = Table[S[i][x[i]] == y[i], {i, 1, Length[data] - 1}];
Do[AppendTo[eqns, S[i][x[i + 1]] == y[i + 1]], {i, 1, 
   Length[data] - 1}];
Do[AppendTo[eqns, S[i]'[x[i + 1]] == S[i + 1]'[x[i + 1]]], {i, 1, 
   Length[data] - 2}];
AppendTo[eqns, S[1]'[x[1]] == 0];
coeffs = Solve[eqns];
Do[Sp[i][x_] = S[i][x] /. coeffs;

  Print[Sp[i][x]], {i, 1, Length[data] - 1}];
s1plot = Plot[Sp[1][x], {x, 0, .2}, PlotStyle -> Red];
s2plot = Plot[Sp[2][x], {x, .2, .4}, PlotStyle -> Green];
s3plot = Plot[Sp[3][x], {x, .4, .6}, PlotStyle -> Red];
s4plot = Plot[Sp[4][x], {x, .6, .8}, PlotStyle -> Green];
s5plot = Plot[Sp[5][x], {x, .8, 1.0}, PlotStyle -> Red];
splot = Plot[Cos[6*Pi*x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Black];
dataplot = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black];
Show[splot, dataplot, s1plot, s2plot, s3plot, s4plot, s5plot, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

As you can see, that once I have enough points it will become tedious. I'm just not sure how to automate the plotting of all the functions in `Sp[i][x]` and plot them over their respective domains.

Comment: `Table[Plot[Sp[i][x], {x,.2 (i-1),.2 i} ] , {i,5}]`

Comment: @george2079 Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part repeats the part of your code that I didn't change much.

```
data = Table[{i, Cos[6*Pi*i]}, {i, 0, 1, .20}];
dataplot = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Black, AbsolutePointSize[8]}];
splot = Plot[Cos[6*Pi*x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Black];
S[i_][x_] = a[i] + b[i]*x + c[i]*x^2;
Do[x[i_] := data[[i, 1]], {i, 1, Length[data]}];
Do[y[i_] := data[[i, 2]], {i, 1, Length[data]}];
eqns = Table[S[i][x[i]] == y[i], {i, 1, Length[data] - 1}];
Do[AppendTo[eqns, S[i][x[i + 1]] == y[i + 1]], {i, 1, Length[data] - 1}];
Do[AppendTo[eqns, S[i]'[x[i + 1]] == S[i + 1]'[x[i + 1]]], {i, 1, Length[data] - 2}];
AppendTo[eqns, S[1]'[x[1]] == 0];
coeffs = Solve[eqns];
Do[Sp[i][x_] = S[i][x] /. coeffs, {i, 1, Length[data] - 1}]
```

Preparing the arguments that are needed to do multiple plots of `Sp[i][x]`

```
args =
  With[{max = 5},
   {Table[Sp[i][x], {i, max}],
    {x, Sequence @@ #} & /@ Partition[Subdivide[1., max], 2, 1],
    PadRight[{}, max, PlotStyle -> # & /@ {Red, Green}]}];
```

Combining the plots.

```
Show[splot, dataplot, MapThread[Plot[#1, #2, #3] &, args], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

For setting up the equations, you might also dispense with the `Table` and `Do` expressions and more tersely do this:

```
x = 0.2 Range[0, 5];
y = Cos[6 Pi x];
data = Transpose[{x, y}];
n = Length[x];

s[i_][x_] := a[i] + b[i] x + c[i] x^2

eq0[i_] := s[i][x[[i]]] == y[[i]]
eq1[i_] := s[i][x[[i + 1]]] == y[[i + 1]]
eq2[i_] := s[i]'[x[[i + 1]]] == s[i + 1]'[x[[i + 1]]]
eq3 := s[1]'[x[[1]]] == 0;
eqns = Join[eq0 /@ Range[n - 1], eq1 /@ Range[n - 1], eq2 /@ Range[n - 2], {eq3}]
```